# Обработка пароля

Tags: php, filter, password

Здравствуйте! У меня хеширование пароля с солью. Не стал использовать рег.выражение для валидации пароля, пускай вводит что хочет.
Только вот для обработки пробелов сделал так.

```
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;
$password = str_replace(" ","4i0",$password); // такая же обработка при аутентификации
```

Как думаете этого хватит? C `str_replace` никаких казусов не будет?

Comment: Вам нужны http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php и http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php и все.

Comment: @Visman да это понятно, я их использую. Я акцентирую внимание на оптимальной обработке пробелов на стороне сервера.

Comment: Оптимально - не изобретать себе лишних проблем. Если пользователь хочет пароль с пробелами - пусть будет. Зато эта подстановка может резко всплыть потом, где ее не будут ждать.

Comment: @bukkojot просто использую activerecord, а он почему-то ругается когда ввожу пароль с пробелами

Comment: @phpХ, а чего activerecord ругается вдруг? Вы пароли что ли пишите в базу, а не их хеши?

Comment: @Visman все в порядке, забыл убрать trim в одном месте :)